# Copy GoogleSheet from Google Driver to Dropbox

Tags: java, api, google-sheets

My scenarios is:
I already had a Google Sheet in Google Drive. Using Java, I would like to move data from this file to a second GoogleSheet file in Dropbox. Another solution that we could copy GoogleSheet from GGDrive -> Dropbox.

1.Could someone have any solution for this scenarios?

2.So someone here know that Could we use Google Sheet API for coding for GGSheet on Dropbox ? GGSheet API here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create